# Trying to run Self Control block as a launchd daemon, get 'error 78' in Launch Control

Tags: macos, launchd, selfcontrol

I'm using [Self Control](https://selfcontrolapp.com/) to block distractions, and I'm trying to run it daily using the OSX `launchd` utility with the Launch Control GUI. This calls a script that figures out the amount of time to block then starts Self Control for that amount of time:

```
#!/bin/sh
#start Self Control block from Terminal
#see https://github.com/SelfControlApp/selfcontrol/wiki/Running-SelfControl-from-the-Terminal    

#calculate block length in minutes
minutes_to_block=`python timetoblock.py`
#timetoblock prints "-1" if the time is between 5 and 10 pm
if [[ $minutes_to_block -le 0 ]]; then echo "done"; exit 0; fi    

#tell Self Control what the block length is (by modifying its defaults)
defaults write org.eyebeam.SelfControl BlockDuration $minutes_to_block    

#start block
sudo /Applications/SelfControl.app/Contents/MacOS/org.eyebeam.SelfControl $(id -u $(whoami)) --install
```

[Here's the screen I see when I try to load/start the daemon in Launch Control.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf3NF.png)

When I hover over "Error 78" on that screen it talks about exit codes, so I figure it has to do with the "exit 0" in my script. However, I'm kind of a bash noob, so I don't know how else I could stop the script. Is there another way, or is the issue with how `launchd` interprets things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your script is not executable. I've just released a new version of LaunchControl which provides a better problem description and a QuickFix button to solve the issue.

Comment: Assumptions don't make good answers. This should have been a comment.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: The script being not executable *is* the problem. I have rephrased my answer accordingly.